# mongodb fetch alternate records

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in mongodb which stores the eventId, eventTime and status (boolean field).

When an event starts, a document is inserted with event start time and status as 'started' with a new eventId. When the event ends, another document is inserted with event end time and status as 'ended'.

I need to fetch all events with their start time, end time, and status.

How to do it in mongodb?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Someone please help.

Comment: What have you tried? Seems like `$group` might accomplish your goals

Answer (score 0):

I tried using $group, but wanted to know if there is any better way to do the same. The following is what I tried to do.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
, { $group: { _id: 'eventId', docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } }
, {
    $project: {
        pair: {
            $zip: {
                inputs: [{ $concatArrays: [[false], "$docs"] }, "$docs"]
            }
        }
    }
},
{ $unwind: "$pair" },
{
    $project: {
        prev: { $arrayElemAt: ["$pair", 0] }
        , next: { $arrayElemAt: ["$pair", 1] }
    }
}
, {$project: {
        _id: 0
        , status: '$status'
        , startTime: '$prev.eventTime'
        , endTime: '$next.eventTime'
    }
  }
])
```